# How to find string in item of list python

Tags: python, list, search, split, find

I need your help because want to find a str in a list for to get complete item.

`my_list:` looks like:

```
['Mont Saint Martin, 42 rue de Bordeaux', 'Mont de Marsan, 100 avenue Pierre de Coubertin', 'Lyon, 56 rue du Docteur Alb\xc3\xa9ric Pont', 'Lille, 90 rue d\xe2\x80\x99Arras', 'Lyon, 2 all\xc3\xa9e des fleurs']
```

`str:` looks like:

"saint" or "de"

Expected list after processing i want to check before ',':

```
['Mont Saint Martin']
```

or for str = "de"

```
['Mont de Marsan']
```

I have try with:

```
new = filter(lambda x: x.my_list == str, x)[0]
```

Thanks for you help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service

Comment: I have try new = filter(lambda x: x.my_list == str, x)[0]

Comment: new = [x for x in my_list if re.search(str, x)]

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers why you cry ? if i ask the question is because since morning i have try to find alone

Comment: @TheFirstLoop "de" would also match `Mont Saint Martin, 42 rue de Bordeaux` if `in` is used do you want that

Comment: @TheFirstLoop please edit your post with the code you've tried (complete code, including regexps definitions) and what went wrong.

Comment: BTW, do not use `str` as a variable name because that "shadows" the built-in `str` function. That means if you later try to use the `str` function Python will think you mean the `str` variable and your program will probably crash.

Comment: @PM2Ring thx but no i have just use str for explain my ask ^^

Comment: I see. Please use proper variable names in your questions, otherwise it can be confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cities = [w.split(',')[0] for w in my_list]
term = "de"
results = [city for city in cities if term in city.lower()]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `re.match` function.

```
>>> l = ['Mont Saint Martin, 42 rue de Bordeaux', 'Mont de Marsan, 100 avenue Pierre de Coubertin', 'Lyon, 56 rue du Docteur Alb\xc3\xa9ric Pont', 'Lille, 90 rue d\xe2\x80\x99Arras', 'Lyon, 2 all\xc3\xa9e des fleurs']
>>> st = ["saint","de"]
>>> for i in st:
        for j in l:
            for x in j.split(','):
                if re.match(r'(?i)\S+ ' + i + r' \S+$', x):
                    print(x)


Mont Saint Martin
Mont de Marsan
>>>
```